# Groovy script to validate ResponseData in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, httpresponse

I have written this script to verify field types, but i'm not sure if it is being validated correctly. Also i want to verify all the expected fields are seen. 
This is my BSF Assertion:

[image]

```
import groovy.json.*;

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

def eventName = json.event_name
(eventName.getClass() == String)

def eventDate = json.event_start
(eventDate.getClass() == Date)

def attendeeLimit = json.attendee_limit
(attendeeLimit.getClass() == Integer)

def orderCount = json.order_count
(orderCount.getClass() == Integer)

def attendanceLimit = json.attendance_limit_on
(attendanceLimit.getClass() == String)
```

Comment: Why do you want to check the type of the objects instead of the values? Also you are performing a comparison but you're missing `assert` keyword. Can you explain what do you want to check exactly?

Comment: i'm trying to do 2 things here: 1. Check all expected fields are present even if they may have null values. 2. Validate the field value is a certain type per Business rule eg. String, Numeric, Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to check JSON response data types change your lines like

   ```
   (eventName.getClass() == String)
   ```

   to

   ```
   assert eventName instanceof String
   ```

   [See Groovy Testing Guide](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html) for details
2. I would suggest switching fro BSF Assertion to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as it is able to compile the script and cache hence your script will perform much better. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for comprehensive explanation and scripting best practices.

---

There is also a [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), this one is mainly used to check response content