# JMeter Beanshell groovy script doesn't work

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I added a BeanShell Assertion to my JMeter testcase.
I want to check a JSON document in JMeter from an API.

My script looks like this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonText = '''
{
    "message": {
        "header": {
            "from": "mrhaki",
            "to": ["Groovy Users", "Java Users"]
        },
        "body": "Check out Groovy's gr8 JSON support."
    }
}      
'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)

def header = json.message.header
assert header.from == 'mrhaki'
assert header.to[0] == 'Groovy Users'
assert header.to[1] == 'Java Users'
assert json.message.body == "Check out Groovy's gr8 JSON support."
```

If i'm trying to start my testcase, i got the following response in my View Results Tree:

```
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import groovy.json.*   def jsonText = ''' {     "message": {         "header": { . . . '' Encountered "def" at line 3, column 1.
```

[image: Screenshot]

How can i fix this issue?

Edit: 
Screenshot JSR223 Assertion
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Try to use JSR223 Assertion with the same code but choose groovy as language

Comment: If i'm trying the script in a JSR223 Assertion with language groovy, i got no feedback to the JSR223 Assertion in my Results tree. But the test have to be failed.

Comment: can you explain why it has to fail, like if you change (assert header.to[1] == 'Java Users') to (assert header.to[1] == 'Java Users123123') it will fail.

Comment: The test has to fail, because the structure of the JSON Document from the API is diffrent to my groovy test-script. But in JSR223 Assertion i got no response about the test result. No win or fail response.

Comment: Pleas have a look into the screenshot: [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw2zT.png)

Comment: If the sampler passes, it means it passed the assertion, also in the above groovy code i dont see you asserting anything other than the jsonText which has the same values as the assertion, so it will pass

Comment: But why didn't groovy check the response JSON document from the API against the JSON document in the groovy script?

Comment: if you want to validate your json response, why not use JSON Path Assertion plugin? it would be way easier for you

Comment: Because i have to check a very long JSON document of validity. With the JSON Path Assertion plugin i only can check one JSON Path, not a completly structure.

Comment: I see, i think you should check this question, you can restructure your groovy code to validate the json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280950/groovy-script-to-validate-responsedata-in-jmeter

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your script:

1. Your JSON is not a valid one, you need to escape quotes
2. Groovy [assert keyword](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html) won't cause assertion failure, it will only print exception into *jmeter.log* file, if you need to fail assertion itself you need to use [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) shorthand instead

Reference code:

```
def jsonText = '{\n' +
        '    "message": {\n' +
        '        "header": {\n' +
        '            "from": "mrhaki",\n' +
        '            "to": ["Groovy Users", "Java Users"]\n' +
        '        },\n' +
        '        "body": "Check out Groovy\'s gr8 JSON support."\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '}'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)

def header = json.message.header
if (header.from != 'mrhaki' || header.to[0] != 'Groovy Users' || header.to[1] != 'Java Users' || json.message.body != "Check out Groovy's gr8 JSON support.") {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('There was a problem with JSON')
}
```

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy with JMeter