# JMeter Assertion failure with groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Update: 
I want to check a JSON document on his structure. I created a JSR223 Assertion with language groovy. My code to check the JSON structure looks like this:

```
import groovy.json.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers;

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("Response" + response);
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response);

//tests
def query = json.query;
assert query instanceof String;

def totalResults = json.totalResults;
assert query instanceof Integer;

def from = json.from;
assert from instanceof Integer;

def to = json.to;
assert to instanceof Integer;

assertionResult = new AssertionResult("Assertion failed! See log file.");
assertionResult.setError(true);
assertionResult.setFailureMessage(e.toString());
```

The validation in the JMeter logfile works great.
But in my View Result Tree, i got the following error message:

```
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script27.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.apache.jmeter.samplers
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.apache.jmeter.samplers;
   ^

Script27.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class AssertionResult 
 @ line 21, column 19.
   assertionResult = new AssertionResult("Assertion failed! See log file.");
                     ^

2 errors
```

I want to see if the test result is successful or not.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you try to use it directly like dmitri suggested? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153653/jmeter-beanshell-groovy-script-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment75326344_44153653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't instantiate AssertionResult class, it is **pre-defined**

   [image: JSR223 Assertion Result]
2. **Don't use [Groovy assert keyword](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html)**, **it won't fail the parent sampler** as expected, refer below example simple code

   ```
   if (1 != 2) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("1 is not equal to 2")
   }
   ```

   once you get it working like below:

   [image: JSR223 Assertion sample]

   you can start modifying your tests as required

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide to learn more about using assertions in JMeter tests.